# How to get current path/route in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, path, sinatra, render

I'd like to get the current path/route to use in an if statmenent in one of my views.

For example, I'd like to achieve something like this:

example.erb:

```
<h4>Foobar<h4>
<p>foo bar foo bar foo bar</p>
<% if current_route == /hello %>
  <%= erb :_hello %>
<% end %>
```

app.rb:

```
get '/foobar' do
  erb :example
end

get '/hello' do
  erb :example
end
```

This way, two routes go to the same view, but if accessed via `/hello`, it will render an extra partial `_hello.erb` onto the view.

Is this possible in Sinatra? What's the best way to achieve it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe you are going to want to use the `request` object. `request.path_info` should give you what you are looking for.

http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#path_info